# Getting the xs:choice maxOccurs and minOccurs attributes with XSOM

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, xsom

I have a following piece of schema code:

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:element ref="ref1"/>
  <xsd:element ref="ref2"/>
  <xsd:element ref="ref3"/>
  <xsd:element ref="ref4"/>
  <xsd:element ref="ref5"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

I am using XSOM library for Java and I would like to retrieve information about the minOccurs and maxOccurs described in the xsd:choice element. I have looked around in the Internet but could only find solutions for retrieving this information from the actual elements, but not the xs:choice element.

I've also identified the place where I can "catch" the xs:choice element:

```
public void startElement(XSModelGroup arg0) {
  if (arg0.getCompositor() == XSModelGroup.CHOICE) {

  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to make a distinction between multiple choice "choices" and ones that are single choice. If somebody could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're starting with the XSComplexType, you can get from that to the XSContentType, and from XSContentType you can do asParticle() to get the content as a particle; and from a particle you can do getTerm() to get its children in the component structure hierarchy; for a term that's a mode group (including perhaps an xs:choice) you can then do asModelGroup() to get the next level. The XSParticle is where the minOccurs() and maxOccurs() properties are available. It's a pretty strange model.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to extract this information from an <xs:element> as well?

    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="ref1" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:group ref="ref2"/>
      <xsd:element ref="ref3" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element ref="ref4" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>

From something like this